# Как сделать tasks.loop автоматического разбана после истечения времени, используя SQLITE3 Discord.py?

Tags: python, бот, sqlite3, discord.py

нужна помощь уже два дня не могу сделать функцию для того чтобы по истечению времени пользователя разбанивало.
Данные хранятся в базе данных SQLite3, дата бана в формате 21-11-2021
Вставил код кмд бана, библиотеки, sqlite3, tasks разбана.
Вот код:

```
    import discord
    from discord import *
    from discord.ext import commands, tasks
    from discord.ext.commands import Bot
    from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle
    import sqlite3
    import threading
    from datetime import datetime
    from datetime import date
    from datetime import timedelta
    import time
    
    # DataBase
    db = sqlite3.connect('baza.db', check_same_thread=False)
    sql = db.cursor()
    sql.execute(f"SELECT * FROM settings")
    if sql.fetchone() is None:
        sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO settings VALUES ('.')")
        db.commit()
    else:
        pass
    
    # Configs
    for settings in sql.execute(f"SELECT * FROM settings"):
        PREFIX = settings[0]
    lock = threading.Lock()
    intents = discord.Intents().all()
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX,intents=intents)
    sql.execute(f"SELECT * FROM bans")
    getallbannedid = []
    for getallbid in sql.execute(f"SELECT * FROM bans"):
        getallbannedid += [getallbid[0]]
    print(getallbannedid)
    
    # Евенты
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        DiscordComponents(client)
        print("Бот запущен!")
        ban_loop.start()
        await client.change_presence(status = discord.Status.online, activity = discord.Game('by semmy#0068'))
    # команды
    @client.command(pass_context=True)
    async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, daysss, reason, daysdelmsg):
        for info in sql.execute(f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = {ctx.author.id}"):
            accessquery = 3
            if info[1] >= accessquery:
                currenttime = datetime.now()
                getuserid = member.id
                emb = discord.Embed(description = f'**Блокировка аккаунта**', colour = discord.Color.red())
                emb.add_field(name = '**Пользователь**', value = f"")
                emb.add_field(name = '**Причина**', value = f"{reason}")
                emb.add_field(name = '**Длительность**', value = f"{daysss} дней")
                emb.add_field(name = '**Дата выдачи**', value = f"{currenttime}")
                emb.add_field(name = '**Модератор**', value = f"")
                emb.set_footer(text="© FakePixel Administraion")
                emb.set_author(name=client.user.name, icon_url=client.user.avatar_url)
    
                global getuserbannedid
                getuserbannedid = member.id
    
                sql.execute(f"SELECT banned FROM bans WHERE banned = {getuserid}")
                if sql.fetchone() is None:
                    getnowdata = datetime.now().date()
                    dayss = getnowdata + timedelta(days=int(daysss))
                    sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO bans VALUES ({member.id}, {ctx.author.id}, '{dayss}', '{reason}', '{currenttime}')")
                    db.commit()
                else:
                    sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO bans VALUES ({member.id}, {ctx.author.id}, '{dayss}', '{reason}', '{currenttime}')")
                    db.commit()
    
                await member.ban(delete_message_days=daysdelmsg)
                await ctx.send(embed=emb)
    
    @tasks.loop(seconds=2.0)
    async def ban_loop():
        await client.wait_until_ready()
        for bans in sql.execute(f"SELECT * FROM bans"):
            getdatanow = datetime.now().date()
            await client.wait_until_ready()
            if str(getdatanow) > bans[2]:
                guild = client.get_guild(806633419865718784)
                await guild.unban(getallbannedid[4])
                print(getallbannedid[4])
                sql.execute(f"DELETE FROM bans WHERE banned = {bans[0]}")
                db.commit()
                print('Пользователь разбанен по истечению длительности наказания')
```

как выглядит база:
Таблица: bans
[image]

Таблица: users (мб пригодится)
[image]

Прошу помогите, функция автоматического разбана после истечения срока бана.

Comment: А в чём ошибка? И да, datetime в db лучше записывать в типе `datetime`

Comment: я не понимаю как сделать эту функцию, у меня просто не работает.
пишет 'int' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: А как вы вводите команду?

Comment: Команду бана - .ban упоминание дни причина за сколько дней удалить сообщения пользователя
пример: .ban nosemka1 test 1

Comment: a параметр `daysdelmsg` не указываете?

Comment: Да, конечно. Дело тут не в бане, а как сделать правильно функцию разбана

Comment: Насколько мне известно, guild.unban() принимает класс discord.User (он же discord.Member). Если я правильно понял, вы передаёте в функцию айди юзера, а не его класс. Чтобы передать класс запишите его в перменную при помощи `Client.get_user(userid), а дальше переменную передавайте в unban().